# Inputting data from file into tuple

Tags: python, csv

I'm learning python and a task is asking for us to input the data from a csv file into a tuple so that we can work out the mean medium and mode of the data. 
What would be the best way to do this without using the csv module.
So far I have

```
    with open(fileInput, 'r') as f:
    temps = []
    for line in f:
        temps.append((line.split(':'. 1)
        print (temps)
```

This is from looking at other questions on here and trying to piece together something but I've hit a wall.

The data is a bunch of temperatures like this:
`Sydney, 23.6, 34.2, 23.4, 34.0, 32.1, 25.6, 25.5,`

After getting it into a tuple as well how to a access the data to work out the things I need to.

---

My code now looks like this

```
with open(fileInput, 'r') as f:
    heights = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        numbers = line.split(',')
        heights.append((numbers[0], numbers[1:]))

    print (heights)
```

How do I now use these lists/tuples in my equations when working out the mean etc?

Comment: `temps.append((line.split(':'. 1)` syntax error spotted. Also why do you split on `:` rather than `,`?

Comment: Also, what wall have you hit exactly?

Comment: That is the error im getting. I removed `(':'. 1)` and replaced it with `(',')` and it gives syntax error again

Comment: Does the file only contain a single line of data, or are there multiple lines that look like that example? FWIW, using  tuple to store data is _not_ a great choice when you want to find the median and the mode.

Comment: being able to get any further with it, as well as the one next to my computer

Comment: contains 3 different city temperature sets. What would you recommend using instead?

Comment: you need another `)` on that line

Comment: And you need one less `(` on that line.

Comment: I got it to print out the data but it looks like this now.
`[['Sydney', ' 23.6, 34.2, 23.4, 34.0, 32.1, 25.6, 25.5\n'],`
With the other data following behind it. How do I remove the \n and would these be usable in working out the mean ect

Comment: I recommend using a list to hold a line's temperature data, but you can put that list into a tuple. For example: `('Sydney', [23.6, 34.2, 23.4, 34.0, 32.1, 25.6, 25.5])`. And you can put all the city tuples into one list.

Comment: what do I change to get it to do that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a homework problem, so I won't give you the complete solution, but this should be enough to get you started.

First, here's a small file of test data based on the line in your question. Your question would be better if it contained some test data like this, as that makes it easier for people testing your code and their answers

**temps.txt**

```
Sydney, 23.6, 34.2, 23.4, 34.0, 32.1, 25.6, 25.5,
Melbourne, 13.6, 24.2, 13.4, 24.0, 22.1, 15.6, 15.5,
Darwin, 33.6, 44.2, 33.4, 44.0, 42.1, 35.6, 35.5,
```

**the program**

```py
filename = 'temps.txt'

all_temps = []

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
        city = line[0]
        temps = [float(s) for s in line[1:] if s]
        all_temps.append((city, temps))

for city, temps in all_temps:
    print('city:{0}, temps:{1}'.format(city, temps))
```

**output**

```
city:Sydney, temps:[23.600000000000001, 34.200000000000003, 23.399999999999999, 34.0, 32.100000000000001, 25.600000000000001, 25.5]
city:Melbourne, temps:[13.6, 24.199999999999999, 13.4, 24.0, 22.100000000000001, 15.6, 15.5]
city:Darwin, temps:[33.600000000000001, 44.200000000000003, 33.399999999999999, 44.0, 42.100000000000001, 35.600000000000001, 35.5]
```

This line:

```
line = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
```

splits the line from the file on the commas, saving the result in a list, and then we scan through the strings in this list stripping off any white space (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) from each of those strings, accumulating them into a list.

This line:

```
temps = [float(s) for s in line[1:] if s]
```

creates a new list from the temperature values, converting the strings into floating-point numbers so we can perform arithmetic on them (eg calculating the mean), and so we can sort them numerically (which is necessary to find the median and the mode).

Comment: @Asharn: The easiest way to  reference the data inside the tuple is the way I've done it in the `for` loop that prints each row of the `all_temps` list. Inside that loop you can do `print(temps[0])` and it'll print the 1st temperature in the list for that city. And you can even do `sum(temps)` to get the sum of all the temperatures for that city. You can also do `all_temps[0][1][0]` to get the first temperature for Sydney.

Comment: @Asharn: If my answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you are learning Python, I suggest you study the following before solving your problem:

1. lists and tuples in Python
2. operations on lists and tuples
3. string manipulation
4. list comprehension

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ is a great resource for beginners.

Then you could construct list of tuples like so:

```
[
  ('place1', [t11, t12, t13] ),
  ('place2', [t21, t22, t23] )
]
```

Place names could be strings. It would be good to convert the temperatures to floats to simplify your calculations further.

To calculate mean, median, mode, etc., list comprehension can be used.